# Other Apple ID is shown when attempting to update apps

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

For some reason another persons Apple ID pops up when I try to do updates on my iPhone 6. Don't have a clue how to fix this or stop it.  The name does not resemble my name at all.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 3):

When you attempt to update an app, you need to log in with the Apple ID that was used to install the app in the first place. If you're being asked to enter a different Apple ID, then this app was installed with this different Apple ID.

You need to uninstall these apps and reinstall them with the intended Apple ID.